# LS estimator of linear regression as weighted average

Tags: least-squares, estimators, weighted-mean

I have to prove that LS estimator of $\beta_1$:  $\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\sum_i(Y_i-\bar{Y})(X_i-\bar{X})}{\sum_i(X_i-\bar{X})^2}$
can be expressed as some weighted average, specifically as 
$\frac{\sum\sum_{i<j} S_{ij}*w_{ij}}{\sum\sum_{i<j}w_{ij}}$, where $S_{ij}=\frac{Y_j-Y_i}{X_j-X_i}$.I have just one hint, that $w_{ij}$ is directly proportional to $(X_j-X_i)^2$. There are exactly $n$ pairs of observations, so $\binom{n}{2}$ slopes. Any ideas? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: should the subscript on the sums be $j < i$? $w$ is indexed with $i$ first, but if $i$ is bounded by $j$ it has to be the inner sum

Comment: See Shlomo Yitzhaki, Journal of Business and Economic Statistics, 1996, 478-486, proposition 1, for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show that $\sum_i\sum_j (y_i-y_j)(x_i-x_j) = 2n (\sum_i  y_i x_i  - n \bar{y} \bar{x})$?

Can you show that $\sum_i(y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})=\sum_i  y_i x_i  - n \bar{y} \bar{x}$?